# Converter of the unit of measurement found in the string Python

Tags: python-3.x, units-of-measurement

Hi All
 I came here because I need your help :) 
I need to find in string units of measurement and convert them.  
In my case I looking for grams and milligrams.

Example: 
"text text ... use 0.0075 g" or 
"text text ... use 0.0075g" or 
"text text ... use 0,0075g"

I have regex to find units of measurement:
`re.findall(r"(\d*\.?(?:.|,)\d+)\s*(lbs?|g)" ,text)`

But I'm not sure how to take this piece of matching text, check if they are grams or milligrams  
and in the case of grams multiply by 1000 and modify the string to get:  
"text text .... use 75mg"
 
 
I would be very grateful for your help and and explanation.

Comment: A simple rule can be if <1 then display it in mg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split method to isolate what is interesting for you :

```py
string = "random text text text use 0.0075g"
check = string.split("m")
print(check)
if check[len(check)-1] == "g":
    print("already in mg")
else:
    step = string.split(" ")
    step2 = step[len(step)-1].split("mg")
    newstring = " ".join(step)
    step3 = step2[0].split("g")
    step4 = float(step3[0])
    newstring = newstring.replace(step2[0], str(step4*10000)+"mg")
    print(newstring)
```

I put many "step" variables so you can understand easily.

TWO WARNINGS:

- "use 0,75g" isn't ok -> use a point as a coma "use 0.75g"
- "use 0.75 g" isn't ok -> don't put spaces "use 0.75g"

Comment: It`s working great but assuming when 0.0075g is at the end of the string. In case 'random text text text use 0.0075g some text' does not work properly and I don`t know how to fix it.
But I have fixed the weak points (comma and space between the number and g) you wrote about :)

Comment: I use this to find number:
`import re
string = "Random text word 0.0075g next text end."

pattern = re.search(r"(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(g)", string)
if pattern:
    numer = pattern.group()
    numer1 = (numer.split("g"))
    print(numer1[0])`
then I used what you wrote and it works ok. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are ways to find a known string into a list (the list you obtain with split), but if you don't know the exact string, that may be difficult... If your program works it's the essential !

Comment: Thx for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use "quantulum3", it has a decent parser, after parsing you can check the name of the unit and multiply accordingly.

```
from quantulum3 import parser
parser.parse("random text text text use 0.0075g")
#[Quantity(0.0075, "Unit(name="gram", entity=Entity("mass"), uri=Gram)")]
```